# Can we apply Lindeberg CLT to simple OLS with non-stochastic regressors?

Tags: least-squares

Consider the simple regression model $$ y_i = \beta x_i+\varepsilon_i $$ where $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a sequence of **real numbers**. Assume $E[\varepsilon_i]=0$ and $E[\varepsilon_i^2]=\sigma^2$. My question is, is it possible to apply Lindenberg-Levy CLT on the sample error to get the asymptotic distribution of the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}=\beta+ \frac{\sum_i x_i \varepsilon_i}{\sum_ix_i^2}$? You can assume that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_ix_i^2\rightarrow m$.

My guess is not, since $x_i\varepsilon_i$ are not i.i.d unless $x_i$ is constant for all $i$. If so, how can we find the asymptotics in the case of non-random regressors?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is the emphasis on the generation of $x_i$ as a fixed, non random sequence? Do you suppose that in other regression models $x$ is random and that makes this problem somehow different?

Comment: Yes, as Ben stated, we have a weighted average of random variables.

Answer (score 1):

So far is I can see, it would not be not possible to use the classical Lindeberg-Levy CLT here, because you have a *weighted* sum rather than straight average.  I would assume that the error terms are still IID in your formulation (though you have not stated this), so you will need to apply a version of the CLT that applies to weighted sums of IID random variables.  Your assumed limit result for the regressors ensures that each of the individual weights vanishes in the limit, so that should be sufficient to apply an appropriate version of the CLT for weighted sums.  I would imagine that you can prove it via an application of Lyapunov's CLT plus Slutsky's theorem.